# innerHTML javascript dynamic

Tags: javascript, dynamic, innerhtml

I am currently having some issues with the innerHTML function in a little javascript project.  Essentially, I have a few HTML form checkboxes which change a number (that is displayed on the same page) depending on whether they are checked or not.  The idea is very much like an IP address.  The result is a number between 0 and 255.

What I want to do however is that whenever the user clicks on a checkbox, I need that number to change dynamically.  Idea resembles the concept that is used when we write a question on this forum.  As you type, the text below changes dynamilly to show exactly what is changed as it changes.

My code isn't working too well.  Could you help me please?  It keeps giving me the message "undefined" instead of the sum.  Thanks for your help.

JavaScript

```
function displayOctets01(){
var octet01 = new Array(8);
octet01[0] = document.getElementById('octect0101');
octet01[1] = document.getElementById('octect0102');
octet01[2] = document.getElementById('octect0103');
octet01[3] = document.getElementById('octect0104');
octet01[4] = document.getElementById('octect0105');
octet01[5] = document.getElementById('octect0106');
octet01[6] = document.getElementById('octect0107');
octet01[7] = document.getElementById('octect0108');
var firstOctect;

if(octet01[0]==true){
firstOctect+=1;
}
else if(octet01[1]==true){
firstOctect+=2;
}
else if(octet01[2]==true){
firstOctect+=4;
}
else if(octet01[3]==true){
firstOctect+=8;
}
else if(octet01[4]==true){
firstOctect+=16;
}
else if(octet01[5]==true){
firstOctect+=32;
}
else if(octet01[6]==true){
firstOctect+=64;
}
else if(octet01[7]==true){
firstOctect+=128;
}

document.getElementById("octets01").innerHTML = firstOctect;
}
else if(octet01[7]==true){
firstOctect+=128;
}

document.getElementById("octets01").innerHTML = firstOctect;
}
```

I suspect that something might be wron with how I am handling the variables.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3TyV3/

Comment: Start out with `var firstOctect = 0;` instead

Comment: That solves the undefined issue, Thanks.  but the logic still isnt producing the result that I want.  I will further my investigation meantime.  thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't expecting it to fix everything, I just noticed you were trying to increment a number that wasn't initialized. Try putting it into a http://jsfiddle.net so we can see how you're using this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that the `firstOctet` variable isn't initialized. That needs to be set to `0` at the beginning of your function. Also, without knowing the purpose of your program, it seems that you don't want to be using `else if` - you need to check every checkbox. Also, you shouldn't be comparing the element with `== true`, you should check its `checked` property Also, your jsFiddle was set to run `onLoad`, so the function wasn't globally available. Finally, you didn't have an element with the `id` "octets01" to output to. Try this:

```
function displayOctets01() {
    var octet01 = [],
        firstOctect = 0;

    octet01[0] = document.getElementById('octect0101');
    octet01[1] = document.getElementById('octect0102');
    octet01[2] = document.getElementById('octect0103');
    octet01[3] = document.getElementById('octect0104');
    octet01[4] = document.getElementById('octect0105');
    octet01[5] = document.getElementById('octect0106');
    octet01[6] = document.getElementById('octect0107');
    octet01[7] = document.getElementById('octect0108');

    if (octet01[0].checked === true) {
        firstOctect += 1;
    } 
    if (octet01[1].checked === true) {
        firstOctect += 2;
    }
    if (octet01[2].checked === true) {
        firstOctect += 4;
    }
    if (octet01[3].checked === true) {
        firstOctect += 8;
    }
    if (octet01[4].checked === true) {
        firstOctect += 16;
    }
    if (octet01[5].checked === true) {
        firstOctect += 32;
    }
    if (octet01[6].checked === true) {
        firstOctect += 64;
    }
    if (octet01[7].checked === true) {
        firstOctect += 128;
    }

    document.getElementById("octets01").innerHTML = firstOctect;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3TyV3/2/

Although I won't lie, I'd reorganize some things. Here's how I would do it:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[name="featuresOctet01"]'),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        addEvent(checkboxes[i], "click", clickHandler);
    }
};

function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, callback);
    } else {
        element["on" + eventName] = callback;
    }
}

function clickHandler() {
    var firstOctect = 0,
        checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[name="featuresOctet01"]'),
        i, cur;

    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        cur = checkboxes[i];
        if (cur.checked) {
            firstOctect += Math.pow(2, i);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("octets01").innerHTML = firstOctect;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3TyV3/3/

It uses unobtrusive JavaScript by binding the events in JavaScript, not the inline HTML. I did use the `click` event instead of `change` because old versions of IE has weird behavior for it with checkboxes/radio buttons. The `addEvent` function is just a simple function for binding events in new browsers as well as old IE.

It selects all elements with the name "featuresOctet01" and adds the event to each. Then, in the handler, it loops through each checkbox, sees if it's checked, and then adds a value based on `2^i`.

References:

- `addEventListener`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener
- `document.querySelectorAll`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll
- `Math.pow`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow

Comment: thanks lan, I'll look into your code.  Once I understand it I might implement it.  thanks again for your help!!!

Comment: @thienwgu No problem at all, thanks :) I just updated my answer with how I would do it. I hope it's not too much, and you obviously don't have to use it, but hopefully you learn a few things. Let me know if you have any questions or need more help